# Declaring Class attributes in python from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, self

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so forgive me if the format is not totally correct.

PROBLEM:

Is possible to assign attributes for a class based on a dictionary?.
I would like to go throw the keys of the dictionary and get from there the name of the attributes. I show down an example.

```
class Clase():
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            self.key = dictionary[key]

dictionary={'attribute1': 'Zara', 'attribute2': 7, 'attribute3': 'First'}
PP = Clase(dictionary)
```

Big regards and thanks!!

aMg

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
class Clase():
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            setattr(self, key, dictionary[key])

dictionary={'attribute1': 'Zara', 'attribute2': 7, 'attribute3': 'First'}
PP = Clase(dictionary)

print(PP.attribute1)
```